# Pandas groupby weighted average

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame on which I would like to group by date (`"count_date"` in column in my df) and apply a weighted average on the average speed (`"average_speed"`) weighted by the count (`"count"`).

I'm trying this:

```
df_byday = df_merged.groupby("count_date").apply(lambda x: np.average(x['average_speed'], weights=x['count']))
```

but it returns a ZeroDivisionError as there are some rows where "count" and "average_speed" are equal to 0.

While searching in the Numpy [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.average.html#numpy.ma.average) I could see that `np.ma.average()` could help solve the issue. But when I'm trying to apply it, I have the following error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/ma/extras.py:649: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  avg = np.multiply(a, wgt,
```

Could anyone help and let me know how to deal with ZeroDivisionError in this case?

Thank you very much!

Comment: please provide a reproducible minimal example (input/output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch `ZeroDivisionError` exception

```
def func(x):
    try: 
        return np.average(x['average_speed'], weights=x['count'])
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

df_byday = df_merged.groupby("count_date").apply(func)
```